# Изменение значений переменной тип Any

Tags: kotlin

Прошу пояснить по типу Any.
В описании сказано что ".... каждый тип... считается Any"
При инициализации переменной - все нормально, при смене типа (int на string) все нормально.
При попытке изменение значения (+1) ошибка

```
fun main() {
var w: Any =2222
w=w+1
println(w)
}
```

ошибка: Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:..........

Comment: Kotlin язык со статической типизацией. И тип Any не для того, чтобы использовать его для динамической типизации.

Answer (score 1):

Просто для типа Any не определена операция `+`. Вот и все.

Comment: Все спасибо.
Разобрался. чтобы компилятор не отругивался нужно сначала сделать проверку: if (w is Int) w=w+1

Comment: а зачем вам такие выкрутасы-то?

Comment: Учусь :) На openedu.ru было упомянуто про этот тип как про основу всего, стало интересно что он может. Еще раз всем спасибо